# Entering 3 Numbers in Prompt and Getting the Max in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm new to this.  I'm working on exercises for a class and as the subject states I'm trying to have the user enter 3 numbers in the prompt window that appears.  This works fine, but I'm trying to get the highest number that was entered to appear after the prompt is over.  As I've noted in the code, can anything be added to Math.max to make this work, it's very close to working, but isn't quite there.  I appreciate any help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>
        Number Input with Prompt
    </title>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
        <!--
        var total;
        var inputNumber;
        var value;
        var highestNumber;
        var finalMax = Math.max.  //<-----Can anything be added here to get the maximum number entered in the prompt window that appears?
        total = 0;
        inputNumber = 1;

        while ( inputNumber <= 3 ){
            highestNumber = window.prompt( "Enter number " + inputNumber + " of 3:" , "" );
            while(isNaN(value = parseInt( highestNumber ))){
                highestNumber = window.prompt( "Enter number " + inputNumber + " of 3:" , "" );
            }
            total = total + value;
            inputNumber = inputNumber + 1;
        }
        document.writeln(
            "<h1>The highest number is " + finalMax + "</h1>" );
  // -->
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Math.max.apply(0, [0,0,0].map( prompt.bind(window,"Enter Number") ).filter(Number) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach logs all answers and runs the compare at the end, thus making use of Math.max()

logic = "highestNumber = Math.max(first,second,third)"

```
<script type = "text/javascript">

  <!--

    var total;
    var inputNumber;
    var value;
    var highestNumber = [];
    //var finalMax = Math.max.  //<-----Can anything be added here to get the maximum number entered in the prompt window that appears?

    total = 0;
    inputNumber = 1;

    while ( inputNumber <= 3 ){

      value = window.prompt( "Enter number " + inputNumber + " of 3:" , "" );

      while(isNaN(parseInt( value ))){
       value = window.prompt( "Enter number " + inputNumber + " of 3:" , "" );
      }

      highestNumber[inputNumber] = value;

      total = total + value;

      inputNumber = inputNumber + 1;

    }

    finalMax = Math.max(highestNumber[1], highestNumber[2], highestNumber[3]);

    document.writeln(
         "<h1>The highest number is " + finalMax + "</h1>" );

  // -->

</script>
```

Comment: I appreciate the comments very much.  Thank you for showing several approaches.  It's good to know because there is no set way with scripting.  I took your advice on this post and it worked like a charm.  I knew I was close.  Again, thank you very much!

Comment: Glad it helped you.  Ya, lots of ways to solve something, with practice it will be easier to pick which one is best for the situation.  Go ahead and mark this one as the solution so stackoverflow visitors can more easily see which one you went with.

Answer (score 1):

This approach compares the response to an up-to-date highest.

logic = "If value > highestNumber, highestNumber = value"

```
<script type = "text/javascript">

  <!--

    var total;
    var inputNumber;
    var value;
    var highestNumber;
    //var finalMax = Math.max.  //<-----Can anything be added here to get the maximum number entered in the prompt window that appears?

    total = 0;
    inputNumber = 1;

    while ( inputNumber <= 3 ){

      value = window.prompt( "Enter number " + inputNumber + " of 3:" , "" );

      while(isNaN(parseInt( value ))){
       value = window.prompt( "Enter number " + inputNumber + " of 3:" , "" );
      }

      if (highestNumber == undefined || highestNumber < value) {
        highestNumber = value;
      }

      total = total + value;

      inputNumber = inputNumber + 1;

    }



    document.writeln(
         "<h1>The highest number is " + highestNumber + "</h1>" );

  // -->

</script>
```

Comment: you still have a syntax error at ```var finalMax = Math.max. ```

Comment: They are different answers, the top two lines describe the approach.  Since the question is posted by a student, seems appropriate to show alternatives.

Comment: ooh ok. Have your sintactically correct and well argumented like

Answer (score 1):

A better way to do that would be like this

```
var nums = new Array();
for(var i=0; i<3; i++){
    nums[i] = window.prompt( "Enter number " + (i+1) + " of 3:" , "" );
}

document.writeln("<h1>The highest number is " + Math.max.apply(null, nums) + "</h1>" );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need or want to use Math.max to find your maximum, you should add each valid entry to an array of numbers and call `Math.max.apply(null, numbers);`

The following fiddle shows this in action:  http://jsfiddle.net/T2Gxm/